# Visualization of two terciary vectors

Tags: data-visualization, categorical-data, matlab

Let $x,y\in\{-1,0,1\}^n$ are two tertiary vectors of the same size where $n$ is a large integer such as $n=1000$. I want to see that $y_i=x_i$. Do you have any idea of the visualization of that results? Experiments so far (in Matlab) that provide no useful information:

`plot(x,y,'ko')`

[image: plot(x,y,'ko')]

`imagesc([x,y]')`

[image]

`plot(x);hold on;plot(y,'r')`
[image]

Comment: Are you familiar with [contingency tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table)?

Comment: Yes, thank you, contingency table could be an option. Actually, the contingency plot could be a useful visualization.

Comment: With such a small number of possible data values, the contingency table (which has only nine entries in this case) should be your very first option--and it likely will tell you everything you need to know.